# Is it possible to delete items under "Shared with me" programmatically?

Tags: office365, onedrive, sharepoint-online

Use-case: As part of migration, items whose permission were recently modified  (and other shared items) are visible under "Shared with me" in one drive for business. Requirement is to either hide or delete such items. Such items are modified using particular account.

What have I found? [Per Microsoft](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/see-files-shared-with-you-in-onedrive-2c14e8e6-4e52-4c61-9778-7155d33534a1#ID0EAACAAA=OneDrive_-_Business) one can manually delete items from "Shared with me".

Question: Is it possible to remove such items programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, I don't think it's possible to remove items in "Shared with me" programmatically.

The "Shared with me" in one drive for business(/_layouts/15/onedrive.aspx?view=3) is just an application page. We have to remove items  from "Shared with me" manually. If it is a list, may be we could remove items using some code.